# Tropical versus max-plus

Tags: tropical-geometry

Is the max-plus algebra an example of tropical mathematics or is it an independent structure? How can we turn a max-plus algebra into tropical geometry or viceversa-if possible?

Comment: It would be helpful if we know how much tropical geometry you know. What would you consider "being turned into tropical geometry?"

Comment: I have read the "classical" reviews in the arxiv for newbies. I think I understand now that min-plus/max-plus algebras are both tropical, but I wonder if they are "isomorphic" somehow...

Comment: Just take the functor $F$ sending the max operator to the min operator and each element to it's negative. Should be able to show easily then that this gives an algebra isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

A max-plus algebra is a tropical algebra. See: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0507/0507014v1.pdf